# Cloudflare Header returning IPV6 Address

Tags: php, cloudflare

I have a simple php script that logs users IP addresses when they connect to my website, my website uses CloudFlare. I use `$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];` to return the clients IPV4 address so it can be logged into a file with the date and time, but sometimes it will log a IPV6 Address.

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])) {
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
}
$filename = 'loggedips.txt';
$myfile = fopen($filename, "r") or die("Unable to log IP!");
$string = fread($myfile,filesize($filename)).date(DATE_RFC2822)." -- $ip\r\n";

$fp = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("Unable to log IP!");
fwrite($fp, $string);
fclose($fp);
```

In my logs i'm seeing a mix of IPV4 addresses and IPV6 addresses
`Thu, 23 Feb 2017 19:08:40 +0100 -- 99.253.44.66`
`Thu, 23 Feb 2017 19:10:14 +0100 -- 2003:00o1:4hc0:e68c:3113:7l06:2qf1:6e84`

And logging IPV6 addresses is no use to me so i was wondering how i could fix this issue so i can log just IPV4 Addresses. And what causes this issue?

Answer (score 4):

it's not possible my friend. your guest cant call your server with his **IPv4** or **IPv6**, not at the same time. and witch IP he uses depends on his network configuration and yours.

you can't dig his information without his permission.

Comment: Actually, i found a php script that converts IPV6 to IPV4 and it works, the only thing is is that the IPV6 addresses that get logged go to cloudflare

Answer (score 0):

you can see and examine all client sent headers by manually watching this result.

```
var_dump($_SERVER);die();
```